# Spring MVC special login interceptor

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this small web application, for which I am using Spring MVC 3.0

The way I have implemented the login functionality is via normal Handler Interceptor. i.e. when the request comes in the Session is checked, if it has a User object, else its sent to the login page.

My question is, does Spring have some special Handler Interceptor to implement the login functionality. If not, then I am doing it correct, as explained above. Or is there any better way of doing this.
thanx...

Comment: With spring security, you can set urls for which a user needs to be authenticated. If he's not, he's redirected to a login url.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, my question is, do we have any special interceptor that can be used for authenticating the user authentication. If not, then I think I am doing it right, as explained in the question... or is there a better way implementing the login in functionality...

Comment: I don't know if it's implemented as an Interceptor or a Filter or something else, but that's the functionality it achieves yes. Read the spring security docs for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it correctly. Spring Security also does it in a similar way. But instead of keeping things in a `Session` object, they keep things in another data structure because they store additional things like access rights etc. Once the user is authenticated through the database, the user is cached in the data structure, and the all other requests are then checked against this cache. If user does not exist in the cache, then they are thrown to the login page. You're doing essentially the same thing, but using Tomcat's built-in Session object cache.

If you only need basic security, I would advice you not to go with Spring Security. Over engineering is a bad thing. On the other hand, if you feel the project will expand into an enormous beast, then including Spring Security in the architecture from now is very wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring security for that. It is implement using filters and you can specify a login url, which will automatically get called after a request is received and the user is not logged in.